# selectonemenu gives IllegalArgumentException exception

Tags: jsf-2

I am using a `selectonemenu` to select a group from a list of groups, but it gives me an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.initializeItems(SelectItemsIterator.java:212)
```

```
<h:selectOneMenu   id="group">
    <f:selectItems value=" #{groupBean.getAllGroups(myEntityBean.entitySelected.id)}" var="theGroup" itemValue="#{theGroup.id}" itemLabel="#{theGroup.libelle}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

any ones help , thanks

Comment: Take a good look at a fairly recent jsf tutorial (or even the Oracle docs). You'll see a big difference with your `h:selectOneMenu`. One major attribute is missing

Comment: Tanks il added the value attribut and it works fine